# Can't assign pivottables collection to a variable

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

The line:

```
Excel.PivotTables pvt = (Excel.PivotTables)wks.PivotTables;
```

generates the error:

> Cannot convert method group 'PivotTables' to non-delegate type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTables'. Did you intend to invoke
>   the method?

Why? How can I resolve it?

EDIT:

The entire procedure is

```
    internal static void UpdatePivotTables(Excel.Worksheet wks)
    {
        Excel.PivotTables pvt = (Excel.PivotTables)wks.PivotTables;
        foreach (Excel.PivotTable p in pvt)
        {
            p.RefreshTable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show how `wks.PivotTables` is generated

Comment: I have not mentioned Excel.PivotTables in my code before that line. I'm trying to generate it on the line in my question. I am using the same syntax as when I would generate other variables such as Excel.Worksheet wks = (Excel.Worksheet)AddinModule.CurrentInstance.ExcelApp.ActiveSheet; (<-which does not generate an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wks.PivotTables` is a method. Use `wks.PivotTables()`

PivotTables Object reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821292.aspx